# Wire an existing spring ApplicationContext to REST service with JAX-RS

Tags: java, spring, rest, jetty, resteasy

I could start my application with REST endpoints exposed without problem.
However, I have another spring ApplicationContext created elsewhere and would like to be accessible from my REST endpoints.

Currently, I have to use a Singleton to lookup the beans. But is there a way to wire an existing ApplicationContext?

Below is what I have.

**web.xml**

```
<web-app>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
    <param-value>package1.MyJaxRsApplication</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<beans>
  <context:component-scan base-package="package2.rest" />
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think u will have to package your service interfaces as a separate jar and use it on other application. Together with that you will have to define service consuming spring configuration use it in you other application

```
<bean name="/ExposedService.htm" class="org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerServiceExporter">
        <property name="service" ref="exposedService"/>
        <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.app.client.ExposedService"/>
    </bean>
```